# Class Templates and Friendship in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lookup, argument-dependent-lookup

I am trying to understand how templates and friendship works in C++. So looking/trying out some examples by myself. One such example that i am unable to understand is given below:

**VERSION 1**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//template<typename T> void func4();
//template<typename T> class NAME;
//   template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);
template<typename T>
class NAME {
   

    friend void func4<T>();
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T> (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);
};
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
 
   return 0;
}
```

The above version 1 gives the following error:

```
prog.cc:13:17: error: variable or field 'func4' declared void
   13 |     friend void func4<T>();
      |                 ^~~~~
prog.cc:13:17: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   13 |     friend void func4<T>();
      |                 ^~~~~
      |                      ;
prog.cc:13:22: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
   13 |     friend void func4<T>();
      |                      ^
```

My **first question** is that even though i have commented the forward declarations for both `func4` and `operator<<` template function, then how can i only get error only for `func4`? That is why is there no error for `operator<<`.

Note that i know we need forward declarations if we want to befriend a specific instantiation of a template. That is for

```
friend void func4<T>();
```

to work we need to comment out the statement

```
template<typename T> void func4();
```

and similarly for

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T> (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);
```

to work we need to comment out corresponding forward declaration at the starting of the program. But when i comment out only `template<typename T> void func4();` statement, the program works and and there is no error for `operator<<`. Again why aren't we getting the error for `operator<<` even though i have not comment out the corresponding forward declarations.

My **second question** is that is the statement

```
friend void func4<T>();
```

same as

```
friend void func4<>();
```

Similarly, is the statement

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <T> (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);
```

same as

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <> (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);
```

My thinking is that the statement `friend void func4<>();` is a specialization of the function template declared using the statement `template <typename T> void func4();`. Meanwhile when we write `friend void func4<T>();` we are **explicitly** passing `T` so in this case when we write/call `func4<int>();` the function template `func4<int>` will be intantiated and then occupy memory. On the other hand the specialised template function will already take up some memory since we have to provide its definition before we can call it. So can someone explain whether there **is a difference when we use `<T>` and when we use `<>`**.  In summary, it seems to me that in case of `<>` a user supplied specialization will be used while in case of `<T>` a new intiantion will be created when we call func4(). So there is a difference because in case of `<>` we have to supply a definition which will already take some space(memory) while in the case of `<T>` func4 will only take space(memory) when we use/call it. Is this the correct conclusion?

My **third question** is that i have [read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) that:

> There is no way to explicitly specify template arguments to overloaded operators, conversion functions, and constructors, because they are called without the use of the function name.

According to the above quoted statement we cannot explicitly specify template arguments to overloaded operators, but then how can write `friend std::ostream& operator<< <T> (std::ostream&, NAME<T> const&);` as it overload operator << .

Comment: Please format a bit, wall of text is hard to read.

Comment: @HattedRooster Ok, I have formatted the first and second part of the question. You can check again.

Comment: The quote in the third question talks about using an operator, not about defining it. You can't specify the template argument by writing something like `x << <some_type> z;` (or any other form that you may think of).

Comment: Have you already got all the answers to your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**
There is no error for `operator<<` because you have used `using namespace std;` and in the `std` namespace there is already overloaded `operator<<`.

**Answer 3**
The quoted statement talks about calling(i.e., using) overloaded operators not defining/declaring them

**Answer 2**

*VERSION 1*

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void func4();
template<typename T>
class NAME {
   

    //friend void func4<>();//this does not work because there is no way to deduce the template arguments
    friend void func4<T>();//this works because here we have explicitly passed T as the template argument

};
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME<int> n;
   return 0;
}
```

In **version 1** above we have a function template func4<>. Now when you write `friend void func<T>();` and `friend void func<>();`, you are making the **full specialization** friend of the class template NAME<>. The reason `friend void func<>();` does not work is that there is no way for template argument deduction to work in this case. While when you write `friend void func<T>();` you have explicitly passed the template argument and so this works. This also means that both(`friend void func<T>` and `friend void func<>();`) are essentially the same specialization of the template function func<>. This will be more clear from my next example version 2.

*VERSION 2*

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class NAME;
template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const NAME<T>& );
template<typename T>
class NAME {
   
    //both of the below friend declarations are equivalent
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const NAME<T>&);//this works 
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream&, const NAME<T>&);//this works as well becasue of template argument deduction
    
};
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME<int> n;
   return 0;
}
```

In **version 2** above we have an overloaded operator function template. Both `friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream&, const NAME<T>&);` and `friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream&, const NAME<T>&);` are **equivalent** and are the same specialization of the overloaded template `operator<< <T>`. The **only difference** between them is that the second one uses template argument deduction. This is possible because unlike version 1, we have a function argument that depends on `T` this time so template argument deduction can work. This was not possible in case of function template `func4<>` because that function does not take any parameter that depends on the template parameter.

Comment: **Answer 1** is... at least incomplete. You can remove the `using namespace std;` and the code will still compile in GCC and MSVC (or you can change the operator to, say, `operator+`). Looks like these compilers are pretty lenient with friend operator template specialization declarations, which is a bug; Clang correctly rejects the code in all cases. Note that Clang will correctly reject the code even with `using namespace std;` in it, because, even though there are indeed declarations of `operator<<` in `std`, the friend declaration doesn't correspond to any of them (deduction fails).

Comment: @bogdan The code doesn't compile if we remove `using namespace std;` as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Y3MpHJVNfi3EPIV). And in the same program(whose link i have given in this comment) if you add `using namespace std;` then it will compile.

Comment: You're right that `using namespace std;` influences compilation in GCC with `-std=c++11` (up to `c++17`); I was compiling in C++20 mode and didn't test the others. Even in previous standard modes in GCC with `using namespace std;`, the code will fail to compile if you try to instantiate the template (add `NAME<int> n;` to `main`). This is the important part that I was commenting on: that, even though there are declarations of `operator<<` in `std`, the friend declaration doesn't match any of them, so the program is still ill-formed, even with the using directive in there.

Comment: Come to think of it, whether it's ill-formed, no diagnostic required, or required to be diagnosed is an interesting question :-), but ill-formed it is.